# django-tables2 module missing

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to use django-tables2 in my django project but I keep getting

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-tables2'" error.

installed it with pip install - everything OK.

added `django-tables2` to `INSTALLED_APPS` (it seems the problem is here).

Thanks you.

Comment: post your settings file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a hyphen but the module name has an underscore. The instructions ask you to add `"django_tables2"` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and not `"django-tables2"`.

Comment: How is it even possible to request a module name with an hyphen? I'm not raised a `ModuleNotFoundError`, but a `SyntaxError`...

Comment: upvoted after two years, because sometimes the silliest things get you ^^